# Pass query parameters through htaccess that is already passing parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working with a legacy framework that is using the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /router.php?package=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

and I need to pass existing query parameters to the router.php file as well, for example

```
http://example.com/bingo1/bingo2.html?param1=foo&param2=bar&param3=baz
```

Any ideas, or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: Typo in example url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [L,QSA] after your rule (QSA = Query String Append)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /router.php?package=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

For example, `http://example.com/bingo1/bingo2.html?param1=foo&param2=bar&param3=baz` will call `router.php?package=bingo1&page=bingo2&param1=foo&param2=bar&param3=baz`